# Solr: unload core wait forever after cores swap

Tags: java, solr

I have created a Solr CoreAdminHandler extension with the goal to swap two cores and remove the old one.

My code looks like this:

```
SolrCore core = coreContainer.create("newcore", coreProps)
coreContainer.swap("newcore", "livecore")
// the old livecore is now newcore, so unload it and remove all the related dirs
coreContainer.unload("newcore", true, true, true)
```

After the last statement get executed the Solr log starts printing the following messages forever

> 61424 INFO  (pool-1-thread-1) [   x:newcore] o.a.s.c.SolrCore
>   Core newcore is not yet closed, waiting 100 ms before checking
>   again.

I tried to call the close() method on the SolrCore instance before and after the unload but the result is the same.

Any idea? Can this be a Solr bug?

EDIT
I have created an issue in Solr jira for this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more than 10 days after opening the issue on the Solr jira I have not get any reply (this is not a good sign for an open source community) so I have spent some time to find a workaround. I basically close the references to the core I want to unload before actually unloading it. Here is the code:

```
SolrCore core = coreContainer.create("newcore", coreProps)
coreContainer.swap("newcore", "livecore")

// the old livecore is now newcore, so unload it and remove all the related dirs
SolrCore oldCore = coreContainer.getCore("newCore")
while (oldCore.getOpenCount > 1) {
  oldCore.close()
}
coreContainer.unload("newcore", true, true, true)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue but interacting from the REST API. Swap + unload = wait forever. Do you think I could do anything from outside Java? What about deleting the old core's directory and then performing the unload? Of course I also tried with the async parameter, but the old swapped cores are never deleted that way (with or without deleteInstanceDir). Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about that. I don't know much the HTTP API. Can you delete the old core folder via HTTP? If yes, probably it will throw the same error but it's worth trying it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: When this happens I can't do anything. Even if I unload the core from the admin panel and then delete the physical directory and it's not possible to create a core with the same name. Any clues? anyone?

Comment: I had to do while(core.getOpenCount >= 1), but apart from that, my unit-tests now work, thanks!