# Solr 6.4: Cannot unload core via API or Admin Panel

Tags: solr

The problem is: I tried to replace a core creating a new one with a different name, swapping and then UNLOAD the old one, but it failed.
Now, even trying to clean everything manually (unloading the cores with the AdminPanel or via curl using deleteIndexDir=true&deleteInstanceDir=true and deleting the physical diretories of both cores, nothing works.

If I UNLOAD the cores using the *AdminPanel*, then I don't see the cores listed anymore. But the STATUS command still returns me this:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&core=mycore&wt=json'
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0},"initFailures":{},"status":{"mycore":{"name":"mycore","instanceDir":"/var/solr/data/mycore","dataDir":"data/","config":"solrconfig.xml","schema":"schema.xml","isLoaded":"false"}}}
```

But, if I try to UNLOAD the core via curl:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&deleteIndexDir=true&deleteInstanceDir=true&core=mycore&wt=json'
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0}}
```

and there is no effect. I still see the core listed in the AdminPanel, the STATUS returns exactly the same and of course if I want to access the cores errors start poping up telling me that solrconfig.xml doesn't exist. Of course, nothing exists.

I know if I restart Solr everything will be fine. But I cannot restart Solr in production whenever it gets dirty alone (and it does, very often).
Some time ago I made a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945589/3456290) but I didn't get any useful reply.

Now, the **real** problem is that in production there are other cores working and to restart Solr it takes about half an hour, which is not ok at all.

So, the question is how to clean unloaded cores properly WITHOUT restarting Solr. Please before saying "no, it's not possible" try to understand the business requirement. It MUST be possible somehow. If you know the reason why it's not possible, let's start thinking together how could it be possible.

**UPDATE**

I'm adding here some errors I've found looking at the logs, I hope it helps:

- [Solr init error](https://pastebin.com/hDFs7sPJ)
- [Solr create error](https://pastebin.com/3dAxjEAp)
- [Solr duplicate requestid error](https://pastebin.com/rhaHaupD) (my script tried twice using the same id)
- [Solr closing index writer error](https://pastebin.com/uH3mtqp0)
- [Solr error opening new searcher](https://pastebin.com/mEutXC3e)

I've just noticed that the error opening searcher and the one creating the core are related, both have

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /var/solr/data/mycore/data/index/write.lock
```

Comment: Does the Solr log give any error when you try to swap the core names? Does it give any error when you're unloading the old core? 30 minutes for starting Solr sounds very extensive - are you running through a large amount of warming queries?

Comment: I've just added some errors I found in the logs, but at least for me they're not so clear. Thanks for replying!